# @ForeignKey in Hibernate 3.5-beta1

Tags: java, hibernate

I tried out beta1 of Hibernate, and annotations were supposed to be included, yet when I use the JAR file I cannot find org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey nor any ForeignKey annotation class inside the jar. Has this been deprecated or renamed?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations / EntityManager will be bundled with Hibernate Core 3.5.x **release**; either beta1 does not clarify as release or somehow it got screwed up but it does **NOT** contain annotations or EntityManager.

You'll need to download them separately:

- [Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.zip/download)
- [Hibernate Entity Manager 3.4.0.GA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-entitymanager/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.zip/download)

and add appropriate JARs to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the hibernate-annotations jar I did with 3.2.1 so perhaps you need it with 3.5-beta1 too

Comment: As I mentioned, 3.5-beta1 says they're included starting with that release: "Bundled with Hibernate Core as of 3.5.x" https://www.hibernate.org/6.html

Comment: have you looked in the jar to see if that is the case?

Comment: I have, and I have not found this annotation where I expected it, thus my question to see if anyone knows if there is anything new with regards to the @ForeignKey annotation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate allows to keep foreign key name. Hibernate overrides the foreign key name by @ForeignKey. It has the attribute name that should be defined.

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "state")

public class State {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@ForeignKey(name="FK_COUNTRY")
private Country country;
```

}